# Adding nodes to xml with DOM in inno Setup - strange problems

Tags: xml, dom, inno-setup, pascalscript

Very strange problem: I use the DOM to edit an xml file (a .exe.config file for an app that needs to interact with ours), but seeing as I have to bulk-add several similar sections, I made a function to insert the whole needed block.

Calling this function once works perfectly. Calling it again with different parameters just afterwards gives an exception (see explanation below the code).

The code:

```
// Split a string into an array using passed delimeter
procedure Explode(var Dest: TArrayOfString; Text: String; Separator: String);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  i := 0;
  repeat
    SetArrayLength(Dest, i+1);
    if Pos(Separator,Text) > 0 then
    begin
      Dest[i] := Copy(Text, 1, Pos(Separator, Text)-1);
      Text := Copy(Text, Pos(Separator,Text) + Length(Separator), Length(Text));
      i := i + 1;
    end
    else
    begin
      Dest[i] := Text;
      Text := '';
    end;
  until Length(Text)=0;
end;

// Ensures an XPath exists, creating nodes if needed
function EnsureXPath(const XmlDoc: Variant; XPath: string): Variant;
var
  PathParts: TArrayOfString;
  TestNode, CurrentNode, NewNode: Variant;
  NodeList: Variant;
  i, j: Integer;
  found: Boolean;
begin
  CurrentNode:=XMLDoc.documentElement;
  Explode(PathParts, XPath, '/');

  MsgBox('Array length: ' + IntToStr(GetArrayLength(PathParts)), mbInformation, MB_OK);
  for i := 0 to GetArrayLength(PathParts) - 1 do
  begin
    MsgBox('Current path part:'#13#10 + '''' + pathparts[i] + '''', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    if pathparts[i] <> '' then
    begin
      //MsgBox('Current node:'#13#10 + '''' + CurrentNode.NodeName + '''' + #13#10'Current path part:'#13#10 + '''' + PathParts[i] + '''' + #13#10'List length: ' + IntToStr(NodeList.Length), mbInformation, MB_OK);
      MsgBox('Current node:'#13#10 + '''' + CurrentNode.NodeName + '''', mbInformation, MB_OK);
      MsgBox('Current path part:'#13#10 + '''' + PathParts[i] + '''', mbInformation, MB_OK);
      NodeList:= CurrentNode.childNodes;
      MsgBox('List length: ' + IntToStr(NodeList.Length), mbInformation, MB_OK);
      found:=false;
      for j := 0 to NodeList.Length - 1 do
      begin
        TestNode:=NodeList.Item[j]
        if (TestNode.NodeName = pathparts[i]) then
        begin
          currentNode:= TestNode;
          found:=true;
        end;
      end;      
      if (not found) then
      begin
        newNode := XMLDoc.createElement(PathParts[i]);
        currentNode.appendChild(newNode);
        currentNode:=currentNode.lastChild;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Result:=currentNode;
  MsgBox('Last node:'#13#10 + '''' + CurrentNode.NodeName + '''', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;

// Seeks out a node, returning the node in "resultnode", and whether it was found as Result.
function SeekNode(const ParentNode: Variant; var resultnode: Variant; subNodePath, attrName, attrValue :String; IsFirstCall: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  NodesList: Variant;
  AttrNode: Variant;
  AttrList: Variant;
  Attr: Variant;
  PathParts, NewPathParts: TArrayOfString;
  i, j, truelength: Integer;
  currentPath, remainderPath: String;
  CallAgain,callResult: Boolean;
begin
  Explode(PathParts, subNodePath, '/');
  truelength:=GetArrayLength(PathParts);
  for i:=0 to GetArrayLength(PathParts) -1 do
  begin 
    if PathParts[i] = '' then
      truelength:=truelength-1;
  end;
  if (truelength <> GetArrayLength(PathParts)) then
  begin
    SetArrayLength(NewPathParts, truelength);
    truelength:=0;
    for i:=0 to GetArrayLength(PathParts) -1 do
    begin 
      if PathParts[i] <> '' then
      begin
        NewPathParts[truelength] := PathParts[i];
        truelength:=truelength+1;
      end;
    end;
  end
  else
    NewPathParts:=PathParts;

  CallAgain:=GetArrayLength(NewPathParts)>1;
  currentPath:=NewPathParts[0];
  remainderPath:='';
  for i:=1 to GetArrayLength(NewPathParts) -1 do
  begin
    if (remainderPath <> '') then
      remainderPath:=remainderPath + '/';
    remainderPath:=remainderPath + NewPathParts[i];
  end;
  NodesList:=ParentNode.childNodes;
  //MsgBox('Node count for ' + currentPath + ':'#13#10 + '''' + IntToStr(NodesList.length) + '''', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  Result:=false;
  for i := 0 to NodesList.length - 1 do
  begin
    attrNode := NodesList.Item[i];
    //MsgBox('Current node:'#13#10 + '''' + attrNode.NodeName  + ''''#13#10'Current path:'#13#10+ '''' + currentPath  + '''', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    if (attrNode.NodeName = currentPath) then
    begin
      if CallAgain then
      begin
        //MsgBox('Remainder of path:'#13#10 + '''' + remainderPath  + '''', mbInformation, MB_OK);
        callResult:=SeekNode(attrNode, resultnode, remainderPath, attrName, attrValue, false);
        if callResult then
        begin
          Result:=true;
          if IsfirstCall then
            resultnode:=attrNode;
          exit;
        end;
      end
      else
      begin
        AttrList:=attrNode.Attributes;
        //MsgBox('Node:'#13#10 + '''' + attrNode.NodeName + '''' + #13#10'Attributes count:'#13#10 + '''' + IntToStr(AttrList.Length) + '''', mbInformation, MB_OK);
        for j := 0 to AttrList.length - 1 do
        begin
          Attr:= AttrList.Item[j];
          //MsgBox('Node:'#13#10'''' + attrNode.NodeName + ''''#13#10'Attribute:'#13#10'''' + Attr.NodeName + ''''#13#10'Value:'#13#10'''' + Attr.NodeValue + ''''#13#10'To find:'#13#10'''' + AttrValue + '''', mbInformation, MB_OK);
          if (Attr.NodeName = attrName) then
          begin
            if (Attr.NodeValue = attrValue) then
            begin
              //MsgBox('Attribute found.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
              resultnode:=attrNode;
              Result:=true;
              Exit;
            end
            else
            begin
              Result:=false;
              Exit;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

// Use of SeekNode: Remove node
function removeNode(const ParentNode: Variant; subNodePath, attrName, attrValue :String): Boolean;
var
  resultNode: Variant;
begin
  Result:=SeekNode(ParentNode, resultNode, subNodePath, attrName, attrValue, true);
  if (Result) then
    ParentNode.removeChild(resultNode);
end;

// Use of SeekNode: test node existence
function hasNode(const ParentNode: Variant; subNodePath, attrName, attrValue :String): Boolean;
var
  resultNode: Variant;
begin
  Result:=SeekNode(ParentNode, resultNode, subNodePath, attrName, attrValue, true);
end;

// Adds a single assembly binding block into the xml
procedure AddAssemblyBinding(const XmlDoc: Variant; const ParentNode: Variant; aiName, aiCulture, aiKey, brOld, brNew, cbVer, cbHref: String);
var
  dependentAssemblyNode: Variant;
  assemblyIdentityNode: Variant;
  bindingRedirectNode: Variant;
  codeBaseNode: Variant;
  publisherPolicyNode: Variant;
begin
//        <assemblyIdentity name="ECompas.Runtime" culture="" publicKeyToken="f27ad8cb97726f87" />
//        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.0.1.0 - 3.0.1.133" newVersion="3.0.1.133" />
//        <codeBase version="3.0.1.133" href="[TARGETDIR]Ecompas.Runtime.dll" />
//        <publisherPolicy apply="no"/>

  dependentAssemblyNode:= XMLDoc.createElement('dependentAssembly');

  assemblyIdentityNode:= XMLDoc.createElement('assemblyIdentity');
  assemblyIdentityNode.setAttribute('name', aiName);
  assemblyIdentityNode.setAttribute('culture', aiCulture);
  assemblyIdentityNode.setAttribute('publicKeyToken', aiKey);
  dependentAssemblyNode.appendChild(assemblyIdentityNode);

  if ((brOld <> '') and (brNew <> '')) then
  begin
    bindingRedirectNode:= XMLDoc.createElement('bindingRedirect');
    bindingRedirectNode.setAttribute('oldVersion', brOld);
    bindingRedirectNode.setAttribute('newVersion', brNew);
    dependentAssemblyNode.appendChild(bindingRedirectNode);
  end;

  codeBaseNode:= XMLDoc.createElement('codeBase');
  codeBaseNode.setAttribute('version', cbVer);
  codeBaseNode.setAttribute('href', cbHref);
  dependentAssemblyNode.appendChild(codeBaseNode);

  publisherPolicyNode:= XMLDoc.createElement('publisherPolicy');
  publisherPolicyNode.setAttribute('apply', 'no');
  dependentAssemblyNode.appendChild(publisherPolicyNode);

  // Doesn't work? No idea why it gives it an xmlns while its parent already has one.
  //dependentAssemblyNode.RemoveAttribute('xmlns');

  // It seems the actual variables of the nodes are somehow lost after adding
  // them to a parent - so add everything to them in advance!
  ParentNode.appendChild(dependentAssemblyNode);
end;

function UpdateConfig(const AFileName, Appdir: string; delete:Boolean): boolean;
var
  XMLDoc: Variant;
  RootNode, MainNode, AddNode: Variant;
  bECompasRuntime, bECompasMetamodel, bECompasDatabaseMS:  Boolean;

begin
  try
    XMLDoc := CreateOleObject('MSXML2.DOMDocument');
  except
    RaiseException('MSXML is required to complete the post-installation process.'#13#10#13#10'(Error ''' + GetExceptionMessage + ''' occurred)');
  end;  

  XMLDoc.async := False;
  XMLDoc.resolveExternals := False;
  XMLDoc.load(AFileName);

  if XMLDoc.parseError.errorCode <> 0 then
  begin
    MsgBox('XML processing error:'#13#10 + XMLDoc.parseError.reason, mbInformation, MB_OK);
    Result:=False;
    exit;
  end;
  XMLDoc.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');

  RootNode:=XMLDoc.documentElement;
  if (RootNode.nodeName <> 'configuration') then
  begin
    MsgBox('XML processing error:'#13#10'Root element ''configuration'' not found.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    Result:=False;
    exit;
  end;
  MainNode:=EnsureXPath(XMLDoc, 'runtime/assemblyBinding');

  bECompasRuntime := HasNode(MainNode,'dependentAssembly/assemblyIdentity','name','ECompas.Runtime');
  bECompasMetamodel := HasNode(MainNode,'dependentAssembly/assemblyIdentity','name','ECompas.Metamodel');
  bECompasDatabaseMS := HasNode(MainNode,'dependentAssembly/assemblyIdentity','name','ECompas.Database.MS');

  if (not delete) then
  begin

    if not bECompasRuntime then
      AddAssemblyBinding(XMLDoc, MainNode, 'ECompas.Runtime', '', 'f27ad8cb97726f87', '3.0.1.0 - 3.0.1.133', '3.0.1.133', '3.0.1.133', Appdir + '\Ecompas.Runtime.dll');
    if not bECompasMetamodel then
      AddAssemblyBinding(XMLDoc, MainNode, 'ECompas.Metamodel', '', 'f27ad8cb97726f87', '3.0.1.0 - 3.0.1.133', '3.0.1.133', '3.0.1.133', Appdir + '\Ecompas.Metamodel.dll');
    if not bECompasDatabaseMS then
      AddAssemblyBinding(XMLDoc, MainNode, 'ECompas.Database.MS', '', 'f27ad8cb97726f87', '3.0.1.0 - 3.0.1.133', '3.0.1.133', '3.0.1.133', Appdir + '\Ecompas.Database.MS.dll');
  end
  else
  begin
    removeNode(MainNode,'dependentAssembly/assemblyIdentity','name','ECompas.Runtime');
    removeNode(MainNode,'dependentAssembly/assemblyIdentity','name','ECompas.Metamodel');
    removeNode(MainNode,'dependentAssembly/assemblyIdentity','name','ECompas.Database.MS');
  end;

  MainNode:=EnsureXPath(XMLDoc, 'appSettings');
  if (not delete) then
  begin
    //<add key="logdir" value=".\log" />
    if (not HasNode(MainNode,'add','key','logdir')) then
    begin
      AddNode:= XMLDoc.createElement('add');
      AddNode.setAttribute('key', 'logdir');
      AddNode.setAttribute('value', '.\log');
      MainNode.appendChild(AddNode);
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    removeNode(MainNode,'add','key','logdir');
  end;

  XMLDoc.Save(AFileName); 
  Result:=true;
end;
```

Originally, the `UpdateConfig` function was done like this:

```
if (not HasNode(MainNode,'dependentAssembly/assemblyIdentity','name','ECompas.Runtime')) then
  AddAssemblyBinding(XMLDoc, MainNode, 'ECompas.Runtime', '', 'f27ad8cb97726f87', '3.0.1.0 - 3.0.1.133', '3.0.1.133', '3.0.1.133', Appdir + '\Ecompas.Runtime.dll');
if (not HasNode(MainNode,'dependentAssembly/assemblyIdentity','name','ECompas.Metamodel')) then
  AddAssemblyBinding(XMLDoc, MainNode, 'ECompas.Metamodel', '', 'f27ad8cb97726f87', '3.0.1.0 - 3.0.1.133', '3.0.1.133', '3.0.1.133', Appdir + '\Ecompas.Metamodel.dll');
if (not HasNode(MainNode,'dependentAssembly/assemblyIdentity','name','ECompas.Database.MS')) then
  AddAssemblyBinding(XMLDoc, MainNode, 'ECompas.Database.MS', '', 'f27ad8cb97726f87', '3.0.1.0 - 3.0.1.133', '3.0.1.133', '3.0.1.133', Appdir + '\Ecompas.Database.MS.dll');
```

This code ran fine the first time, but the second time, it gave the aforementioned "**Unknown Method**" error on `setAttribute` in `AddAssemblyBinding`. It got more bizarre... when I removed the three lines setting the attributes to assemblyIdentityNode, the rest of the code DID run fine for the other nodes.

The only thing I could imagine is related is that these are the nodes I query in the `HasNode` function to see if the block already exists. Can DOM not handle querying through unsaved changes? So I edited the code to do the existence checks in advance and store the result in Booleans, because I thought maybe the problem was seeking the nodes on a modified tree. But now it gives an error about trying to nest a node under itself or its own child (**"msxml3.dll: Inserting a Node or its ancestor under itself is not allowed"**), on the `dependentAssemblyNode.appendChild(bindingRedirectNode);` line. Neither of these errors makes any sense whatsoever.

I seem to get loads more like it. `EnsureXPath`, when used a second time in a situation where it had to add nodes, also gave the illegal nesting error. I get the feeling that somehow, the object mysteriously becomes null somewhere, and that that null is seen as the root node in functions handling node objects.

Does anyone have any clue what may be causing this behaviour?

The XML I'm editing typically looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="AppString1" publicKeyToken="43265234666" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.99.99" newVersion="1.2.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="AppString2" publicKeyToken="43265234666" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.99.99" newVersion="1.2.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

(with some more of these dependentAssembly sections... but that hardly matters)

Comment: Note on this: My brother suggested OLE objects may need to be cleaned up, but the inno setup help explicitly says "COM objects are released automatically when they go out of scope. There are no functions to 'destroy' or 'free' them."

Comment: That's fine. If you go out of scope of the function, the local variables are released... What looks suspicious is missing `const` keyword at your `AddAssemblyBinding` function for Variant parameters. They might add a new interface reference (but it's just my guess; I don't precisely know how PascalScript internally handle the Variant parameters). For sure I know that you should use it there.

Comment: And, this question is not answerable unless you post the full script. Ideally with a sample XML file you're trying to modify.

Comment: Hmm. Never knew about the var/const thing. Too used to C#/java I guess... everything non-primitive is by ref there.

Comment: A good post about Delphi `const` directive you may [`find e.g. here`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7642429/960757).

Comment: @TLama: I added the full script. This is simply called in `NextButtonClick` after checking if `CurPage = wpSelectDir`, so when the install path is given. It then checks if the xml is present in the folder (`WizardDirValue()`), and if so, calls `UpdateConfig` with the full xml path, the app dir to insert into the xml, and 'false' on the Delete property (since that's for the uninstall);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, there didn't seem to be any way out of this mess, and I ended up simply making an external app to do my XML edits. The tool for making the xml changes was simply extracted to the program folder, and set in the Run and UninstallRun sections with the correct parameters.

(the UninstallRun part was needed because the XML to edit was part of an external app that needed to be integrated with our app. Obviously, if you're in this situation but need it for xml edits in your own program, simply extracting the app into {tmp} and running it once from there should be enough)

If anyone ever figures out what makes this COM mess fail, though, please do add another Answer. From what I ran into when making the external app, though, it is probably related to the change in namespace halfway in the XML tree.

Comment: Had same problem today.
Seems to be related to the Unicode version of InnoSetup.
It failed in Unicode version, and It worked in Ascii version.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting information. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but further information on the subject.

**Overview**: Unicode Inno installers targeting anything newer than Windows 7/Server 2008 R2 should be fine. For those platforms and older I would not rely on using MSXML inside Inno Setup. I did not test ANSI Inno Setup at all (I've heard there are regularly less issues with things).

**Details**: I too noticed similar issues using MSXML Variant objects. The problems I saw usually occurred when a method using Variants was closing (thus likely freeing resources), and I received the DLL crash. Never had any errors when specifically invoking MSXML methods themselves. So possibly this issue is semi-PascalScript related in how its handling the COM object references? I was developing on Windows 10 and had no issues testing my installer, but only after deploying it did I start to notice the madness. Which eventually led me to believe it is platform dependent.

```
Platform                Version  Works  Notes
----------------------------------------------------------------
Windows 10              NT 10.0  YES
Windows Server 2016     NT 10.0  YES
Windows 8.1             NT 6.3   YES
Windows Server 2012 R2  NT 6.3   YES    Requires .NET 4.5.2
Windows 8               NT 6.2   ???    Most likely works
Windows Server 2012     NT 6.2   YES    Requires .NET 4.5.1
Windows 7               NT 6.1   NO
Windows Server 2008 R2  NT 6.1   NO
Windows Vista           NT 6.0   NO
```

Note that anything based off NT 6.1 or older is where the problems start occuring. I could not test plain Windows 8 but under these assumptions I'll bet it works. I'm doing fairly complex XML manipulation (removing nodes, adding nodes, modifying nodes, and a smattering of various XPath queries with handy XPath methods) so I feel fairly confident that you are likely to see the same results. I do not know why .NET would be required (for the Server 2012 tests) because MSXML is not really related to .NET in any way, but perhaps when installing those Frameworks another 3rd party dependency is updated (which makes everything happy). Even after applying all security updates and fixes for Windows 7 or Server 2008 R2 the problem persists. For all the other platforms I performed NO additional updates after installation (unless noted like .NET Frameworks). All of them were **installed with** the latest Service Pack/Update for that platform.

Any specific version notes

```
InnoSetup-5.5.9(u)

Windows 10 Version 1511 (Updated Feb 2016)
Windows 8.1 with Update
Windows 7 with SP1
Windows Vista with SP2

Windows Server 2016
Windows Server 2012 R2 with SP1
Windows Server 2012
Windows Server 2008 R2 with SP1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that your seekNode function is returning for the first attribute it checked. I guess you need to remove following section:

`else
     begin
     Result:=false;
     Exit;
 end;`

I dont know whether this solves your problem.

Comment: No, because in that branch, it already found the correct node, with the correct attribute, but it has the wrong value. xml can't have multiple attributes of the same name, so at that point, it should abort. I think I understand what you mean, though... that there could be multiple _nodes_. But your proposed fix is far from enough to handle that. Anyway, I changed my approach and did it with an external tool, in the end.